# Binding CommandParameters to Property from other View

Tags: wpf, datagrid, command, prism, commandparameter

I have a view (Main View) with a toolbar and a TabContent region (PRISM).
In the TabContent region I have two tabs (two views -View A, View B-) representing the same model (Contacts) in a different way.

View A contains a DataGrid with Contacts. The toolbar in the Main View contains a "Delete Button" with a DeleteCommand. I want to send with the DeleteCommand the selected contacts from View A as Command Parameters, but with the code I show below, the command parameters are null. It looks like the Main View doesn't retrieve the Selected Items from the DataGrid located in View A. How can I accomplish this?

This is the Main View:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Background="#D6D6DC">
        <ToolBar Style="{StaticResource ModuleToolBarStyle}">
            <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="Contacts"></TextBlock>
            <Button Name="addContactButton" ToolTip="Add Contact">
                <Image Source="/PrismApp.Controls;component/Images/add.png"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Name="deleteContactsButton" ToolTip="Delete selected Contacts"
                    Command="{Binding DeleteContactCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=ContactsList}">
                <Image Source="/PrismApp.Controls;component/Images/delete.png"/>
            </Button>
            <ToggleButton Name="ViewAButton" ToolTip="View A" Command="{Binding NavigateToViewACommand}"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsViewAActive}">
                <Image Source="/PrismApp.Controls;component/Images/listblack.png"/>
            </ToggleButton>
            <ToggleButton Name="ViewBButton" ToolTip="View B" Command="{Binding NavigateToViewBCommand}"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsViewBActive}">
                <Image Source="/PrismApp.Controls;component/Images/tilesblack.png"/>
            </ToggleButton>
        </ToolBar>
    </DockPanel>

    <TabControl Grid.Row="1" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContactsViewRegion">
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

This is View A:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="ContactsList" Margin="20" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResizeRows="False"
              CanUserResizeColumns="True" ColumnWidth="*" ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}">

    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

The view model is the same for Main View, View A and View B.

Comment: and how is the ViewModel made ? Is there a ViewModel for each View or just one for all of them ?

Comment: @NawedNabiZada Just one for all views (Main View, View A and View B)

Comment: Then you could make your life easier and bind your selected item to a property in your VM and in your command you could access that property

Comment: @NawedNabiZada yes, but I don't want to retrieve just one selected item, but all SelectedItems instead. And SelectedItems is a read-only property so it cannot be set by markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what I think you need, the first thing you will need in your view where the DataGrid resides is the following namespace.

`xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"`

This is something like what you will want to add to the DataGrid; specifically, the `i:Interaction.Triggers` part:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ContactsDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}" Margin="20" CanUserAddRows="False"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedItemsCommand}" 
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItems,ElementName=ContactsDataGrid}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
```

The EventTrigger above is what will sync the SelectedItems in the DataGrid with a ViewModel.

ViewModel additions:

```
// A list to store the selected contacts in
private List<Contact> _selectedContacts = new List<Contact>();

// A DelegateCommand that will be invokes when selections change in the DataGrid
public DelegateCommand<object> SelectedItemsCommand { get; set; }
```

In your ctor, or wherever else you bind commands, add this:

`SelectedItemsCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(SelectContacts);`

SelectContacts method that the DelegateCommand calls:

```
private void SelectContacts(object contacts)
{
    var selected_contacts = contacts as System.Collections.IList;
    if (selected_contacts != null)
    {
        _selectedContacts.Clear();
        foreach (var contact in selected_contacts)
        {
            _selectedContacts.Add((Contact)contact);
        }
    }
}
```

You now have a private `_selectedContacts` collection in the ViewModel that contains all of the items selected in the view, and will update when the `SelectionChanged` event fires from the DataGrid in the View.

Do with that what you need to. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.